# Jquery acting strange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not understand how JQuery is acting. I thought I should get these results on alert. `fname` and `zetest`. But for some reason I am getting strange results. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
obj = {};
var test = "try"
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
        test = "zetest";
        var name = $('#fname').val();
        var mes = $('#message').val();


        obj["name"] = name;
        obj["message"] = mes;

    });

    alert(obj.name); // outputs undefined
    alert(test); // outputs try not zetest


    /*var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        socket.emit('message', "dsfsdfs");
    });*/
});
```

Comment: your alerts are OUTSIDE the on submit function ...

Comment: That's expected behaviour... You are setting variables in an event

Comment: Alert them inside the form submit event

Comment: yes, but the thing is I want to edit the values inside the onsubmit function and try to use them outside the onsubmit function. Thought if the variables are global then it should work.

Comment: If you want to use variable outside function then keeping them global will do but make sure that you are setting values to the variable before using them. Here you are setting `obj["name"] = name;` inside submit event of `myform` and trying to read it in alert before any submit event occurs.

Comment: @Jones An event handler isn't called if the relevant event isn't fired

Comment: Yes, I tried to set them global but it does not work.

Comment: Yes, when the form loads it gives me undefined and try, which is fine. I then enter details inside the form and submit, but I still get the same results

Comment: @Jones If you submit a FORM, a refresh/redirect is done, so ya, still 'undefined'. You should read some basic tuto regarding how to handle event, etc...

Comment: Deal with data inside the form submit event, or set them in localStorage then retrieve for later use.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about JQuery. First you just add event listener functions to #myForm's onsubmit. And then you immediately call alert functions. Above anonymus function never fired, just binded to submit event.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is pass the object to the server via the socket.io. I also tried to call the socket inside the event and it does not work. @actionman How do I bind?